# Visual studio 2013 suddenly compiling really slow after BK4503 minor error appeared

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I've started to get this message while compiling

BSCMAKE : warning BK4503: minor error in .SBR file 'C:\leisec-pcpcd.pcpcd\code\PCPCD\Debug\x64\build\Configuration.sbr' ignored

I have not changed the Configuration.cpp file any time recently.
I've tried to delete Configuration.sbr, or clean the solution and rebuild.
This warning reappears.
I don't mind the warning. What I do mind is that since this has appeared, compiling the solution
has become really slow, even when just one cpp file has been altered.

By the way, I've found posts about BK4503 in older versions of MSVS, but these haven't helped me.

Also, this sudden slow compilation is only in debug mode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It worked out.
In case anybody else runs into it:
You go to the Project Property pages ->  Browse Information -> Preserve SBR Files

and set it to `No'

Comment: I suffer the same symptom but setting "Preserve SBR Files" to "No" doesn't help. In fact it was already set to "No" by default.

Comment: Hmm.. if you figure it out please add an answer.

Answer (score 1):

While not Visual Studio 2013, I can reproduce BK4503 on demand in Visual Studio 2015, which may help other Googlers.

This may not be the smallest source to reproduce, but it's of the same form in which I originally encountered it. Doesn't occur in VS2013, but does in VS2015. I'm not sure if this is a bug, so haven't raised it as such yet.

I did try comparing the before and after of the bsc files, but it's really not a skilled area of mine!

Create an empty console project, enable Browse Information, and copy this code. Commenting out the push_back line will prevent the warning; leaving it in will cause it:

```
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

enum return_type
{
    foo = 0,
    bar
};

std::vector<std::function<return_type()>> funcs;

class FooBar
{
public:
    return_type Foobar()
    {
        return bar;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    FooBar fb;
    funcs.push_back(std::bind(&FooBar::Foobar, &fb));
    return 0;
}
```